# How to prevent doubleclicking on a button with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, html

I want to select an element in my case a button on the page in my angularcontroller and then disable it. The button looks like this:

```
myBtn= $element.by.buttonText('submit')
```

I don't want the user to click the button twice in order to avoid to post requests in the backend. When I get the code above I get an angular reference order. What is an easy way to select a button and then set the disabled property to true so the user cannot click the button twice?

Comment: You can declare a variable `mybotton_pressed = false` to assign a `true` when this is been pressed, and the controller does not do anything when this is true. If you mean the dblclick event can create a policy that is responsible for prevent this event.

Comment: Ignore those comments. Don't use jquery or any DOM selectors with AngularJS. You just need directives - `ng-disabled` and `ng-submit` or `ng-click`. Read the docs.

Comment: [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) to start with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-disabled` to disable your button according to a flag set in your submit function. For example:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
  ...
  <button type="submit" ng-disabled="isSubmitting">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
   $scope.isSubmitting = true;
   $http.post('...').finally(function() {
     $scope.isSubmitting = false;
   });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have many buttons on page, then its better to create a directive so that on any button which is clickable, it doesnt get pressed twice

```
app.directive('ngClickDisable', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      clickAndDisable: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      iElement.bind('click', function() {
        iElement.prop('disabled',true);
        scope.clickAndDisable().finally(function() {
          iElement.prop('disabled',false);
        })
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This can be used on a button as follows:

```
<button ng-click-disable="functionThatReturnsPromise()">Click me</button>
```